# Unity desktop folder conundrum

Tags: directory

Ubuntu beginner here. I have 13.04, and whenever I try to create new folders on the desktop I am plagued by two issues:

1. The folder icons start out extremely tiny, so I have to resize them.
2. I can't see the names of the folders anywhere around them.

[image]

Any way to remedy these?

Comment: Could you include a screenshot to illustrate the exact issue?

Comment: Could you try the Guest session and report about the situation in there? If that is correct, then a solution is in the personal settings of Unity/Gnome and if it also malfunctions as a guest, then it's probably a bug, I'd say.

Comment: Hmm.  Have you made modifications to your theme, settings, etc..?

Comment: @gertvdijk: I can't see a guest option or something like that on login.

Comment: I reset the unity configurations via dconf, and now I can see a guest login option (before I didn't even have that) and it's fine in guest mode, but still crappy in normal mode.

Comment: I just reinstalled Ubuntu. Now it's fine... :P

Answer (score 1):

Woha! Isn`t that small :p
Have you tried MyUnity? It is available in the Software Center or using sudo apt-get install myunity . It has a lot of cool features, and I think that one of them is resizing icons... it also has the option to go back to the Ubuntu defaults...

Comment: MyUnity doesn't seem to be in the repo for Ubuntu 13.04 apt and/or Software Center.

Comment: Oh, in Ubuntu 12.04 is available through the Software Center and as "myunity" apt. I beg your pardon, I thought it would be available for 13.04 as well.